# Tips on how to balance Polymorphism/Inheritance/TypeData architecture with Prototype/Flyweight pattern in a complex card game?

Tags: oop, inheritance, kotlin, architecture, polymorphism

I am trying to develop a card game with Kotlin, but I feel like the complex architecture decisions I feel I have to make are stalling my process.
I would like to create a solid and flexible foundation for potentially dozens of different cards with different effects, of different types (e.g. spell, vehicle, weapon...).

Intuitively I feel like giving each different `Card` its own subclass would be ridiculous for several reasons, such as the loss of flexibility (can't (without crazy hacks) create new kinds of cards dynamically) and escalating complexity.

On the other hand, there will be different categories of cards (types) which generally have more in common with each other than cards - so it feels like I should definitely subclass `Card` because otherwise I would end up with Type enums (SPELL, WEAPON, VEHICLE...) and ugly switch-statements replacing what's usually dealt with by inheritance and polymorphism.

I initially had problems conceiving how to access specific behaviors of subclasses who live in collections of superclasses, but I now understand how I can solve this using the visitor pattern - all fine so far.

My problem now is this architectural approach seems to conflict with other things I have planned and which I consider necessary or at least very worthwhile to have:
Hybrid of Prototype-Flyweight-Pattern:
I have created a 'cyclopedia' of prototype cards that can be copied. Cards consist of a shared static part and a unique dynamic part:
[image]

Naturally, I would like to create subinstances of the identifying components in the following manner:
[image]

Doing this doesn't seem to be possible in a satisfying way no matter how I approach it. There are many solutions but all seem like weak compromises to me:

- Doing it the way I described it means subclasses have to save
  multiple references to their components; a baseclass and one subclass
  one for each. It also leads to an ugly situation where type
  attributes are spread over several component-classes all dependent on
  each other.
- Using interfaces instead of inheritance leads to loads of code duplication.
- Subclassing only the components but not card itself hides type information in the innards of cards and also demands ugly reflection
  for accessing subclass traits.
- Implementing a data-equivalent of type-information instead of subclassing to circumvent the limiting rules of Kotlin inheritance
  hierarchies seems to be hacky and removes IDE support.

I am sure there are even more approaches I have considered over the course of the last two weeks, but these are all I can remember right now.

I know that you probably would require more complete information on what I am planning to do to give me concrete answers, but since it's too complex and I don't know all about where this is going either, I am satisfied with rough ideas in the sense of 'consider this' or 'whatever you are doing, stay away from this' or general advice about how to deal with such a 'design crysis' where things seem so complex you don't know how to start.

Of course I am ready to elaborate or detail parts of my description if it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking here.

What about creating a BaseCard class with Card low-level common parts, then a class for each category that inherits from BaseCard, named like Category, where you store each category common parts, and then classes CardofSomeType inheriting from its respective Category. So in a CardofSomeType you inherit anything relevant from either class, and you just add new Card(s)ofSomeType(s) to extend your set.

About what data is instance specific or shared in the class, that's orthogonal to this and an implementation detail of each class.

Comment: I almost had another day to think about this, and I start to feel like I should go in a similiar direction to what you just described.

About the orthogonality of shared and specific state ... I can't use 'real' static properties for this because it would mean that I have to make a new class for basically every card - because every card is mostly consisting of 'shared state'. If you think about what card games usually look like, this makes a lot of sense: Cards with the same name tend to be copies of each other, with differences being stuff like position or modifications such as markers.

Comment: flyweight/prototype looks appropriate to apply too then.

Comment: Gotta try something now. I will eventually update the question.

Thank you for your reply!